# ALTER TABLE IF NOT EXISTS не работает на mariabd ниже 10?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, mariadb

```
ALTER TABLE  post ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS my_id int(11) NOT NULL;
```

Пожалуйста подскажите есть ли замена ALTER TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ?

Comment: Перевести не пробовал? ну давай я помогу: "Изменить таблицу, если её не существует." Тебе не кажется, что фраза немножко нелогичная?

Comment: @Akina странно, я иначе подумал, изменение таблицы post добавив колонку my_id если не существует

Comment: @Akina добавить колонку если ее не существует,  PotroNik описал верно

Comment: Ну так Вы смотрите, что пишете-то! `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN IF EXISTS` - нормально, а Вы что написали? тем более в заголовке... поправьте, что ли.

Comment: @Akina это сокращенный код, полный код в описании же написан )

Comment: Да я вообще не понимаю Вашей проблемы. Добавляйте безусловно. Если поле есть - ну будет ошибка исполнения, обработайте (или вообще - игнорируйте), и вся недолга.

Comment: @Akina, дело в том что я в одном файле делаю много sql запросов, если появиться хоть одна ошибка в этом файле все запросы которые в нем есть не выполняться

Comment: Файл с запросами - это .SQL, типа дамп изменений? тогда ошибка в одном операторе не должна приводить к останову выполнения. Или в файле - SP? ну так определите continue handler, и вся недолга.